# Can someone understand what this Java syntax is doing? And also in what situation would someone use it?

Tags: java

```
public class UpdateDetails<REQ extends ReferenceRequest> extends ExecuteStep<Context, REQ> {

}
```

The syntax just feels very odd to me. I am not even sure what exactlty REQ is. I do not see that used anywhere else in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REQ` is a generic type parameter.

It doesn't have to be used in the `UpdateDetails` class. It is passed to the `ExecuteStep` super class, which might use it.

Suppose `SomeReferenceRequest` is a class that implements or extends `ReferenceRequest`.

You can instantiate your class with:

```
UpdateDetails<SomeReferenceRequest> details = new UpdateDetails<> ();
```

The super class `ExecuteStep` might have methods that return `REQ` or have `REQ` argument[s], or it might have instance variables of type `REQ`.

Answer (score 0):

UpdateDetails: The name of your class REQ: generic name for the class    that UpdateDetails will process. Similar to when you write  ArrayList you will build UpdateDetails. Someclass will need to extend the class ReferenceRequest.

ReferenceRequest: UpdateDetails can use any object that extends ReferenceRequest.

ExecuteStep: UpdateDetails will need to extend the class ExecuteStep,    that will process two objects, Context and REQ.

You can learn more about generics here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/